# Can't update profile because of a non-existent display name change

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

I am trying to change my display name from my profile. When I fill the About Me section and after clicking save changes it shows an error:

[image: This is the error i got!!]

This happens even if I don't change my display name. Why does it happens to me? Is this a bug?

Comment: Err, why the [status-by-design]? If Ahmad hasn't changed his name, surely this is a bug?

Comment: @animuson, I don't think this should be [status-bydesign], as "This happens even if I don't change my display name."

Comment: @Ahmad If you do a fresh load of the page and only edit the bio, does it let you save?