# Profile page prefills my Display name wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Here is a screen dump from Chrome, which shows that on my profile page the display name gets pre-filled on server side (not in my browser) with an old value (my old display name - Jozef Spisiak according to the history) instead of current one - Spiso as you can see as well in screen dump. Therefore every time I want to change anything on my profile page, I have to write into this field manually my current display name. Tested on Safari without extensions and Firefox, where I never logged into Stack overflow before.

[image: Wrong display name]

This has been happening for about 5 days already, so if it is a cache, it is a long one and on server side. Adding references to 3 other tickets, where users had very similar problems and were never solved:
[First](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316900/cannot-save-changes-to-profile-even-though-i-didnt-change-my-display-name) [Second](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317349/updating-profile-picture-profile-bug) [Third](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294851/cant-update-profile-because-of-a-non-existent-display-name-change)

Comment: So is Spiso or Jozef Spisiak the name you wish to be using on SO? (ie: do you actually have the correct name you want to be using now - and it's just a weird bug with stuff happening in the profile page?)

Comment: I would like to use Jozef Spisiak actually, but I can change that in 20 days, when I can change my display name (the 30 days limit). I am not sure how this bug happened in the first place, since all I know is that I registered myself (not sure what I did fill in though, it could have been either of those) and when I tried to get the badge for filling in my bio in my profile, this was already happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was definitely odd; I've resync'd two competing sources of truth; you're currently showing as Jozef, but if you are trying to be Spiso: hopefully if you edit again, it should now work.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped the issue, I can now save my profile without problems. I assume it will be synced to meta in an hour or so. Might be interesting to follow if more of these show up in the future.

Comment: @JozefSpisiak it *should*; is it showing correctly to you on meta now?

Comment: Yes, now my profile is synced correctly on meta too. Thank you for your help.